# Python + BeautifulSoup New York Times Web Article Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the content of any NYTimes article and put it into a string to count certain words. All article contents are found in HTML 'p' tags. I am able to get paragraphs one by one (commented in the code) but I can't iterate over the variable paragraphs because I keep getting the following error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-ccc2f7cf5763> in <module>()
     16 
     17 for i in paragraphs:
---> 18     article = article + paragraphs[i].get_text()
     19 
     20 print(article)

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = requests.Session()
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/01/02/world/europe/turkey-police-thwart-attack-on-prime-ministers-office.html"
req = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
paragraphs = soup.find_all('p', class_='story-body-text story-content')

  #article = paragraphs[0].get_text()
  #article = article + paragraphs[1].get_text()
  #article = article + paragraphs[2].get_text()
  #article = article + paragraphs[3].get_text()
  #article = article + paragraphs[4].get_text()
  #article = article + paragraphs[5].get_text()
  #article = article + paragraphs[6].get_text()

for i in paragraphs:
    article = article + paragraphs[i].get_text()

print(article)
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the NYT Terms of Service too, particularly if you're using their articles for more than a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
for p in paragraphs:
    article = article + p.get_text()
```

or:

```
for i in range(len(paragraphs)):
    article = article + paragraphs[i].get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p_tags = soup.find_all(class_="story-body-text story-content")
# method 1
article = ''
for p_tag in p_tags:
    p_text = p_tag.get_text()
    article += p_text
print(article)

# method 2
article2 = ''.join(p_tag.get_text() for p_tag in p_tags)
print(article2)
```